# get protocol and domain name on localhost and remote server

Tags: php

on localhost my site has this address - `localhost/example.com`
on remote server it is - `https://example.com`

is there a php `$_SERVER` variable - or another way - to get exactly:

- `localhost/example.com` - when I'm on localhost
- `https://example.com` - when I'm on remote server

thanks

Comment: If you want it custom like that (one with just the domain and one with a subfolder), the easiest (and safest) way would probably be to set a config param with the base url for your different environments and call some function that returns it dynamically based on the configured base url, or set it as a constant.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson - where to set the config param?

Comment: Your applications configuration, if you have one. If not, you could write one or use some existing config library from [packagist](https://packagist.org/?query=config).  Or use environment variables. There are many options.

Comment: Use $_ENV and environment variables instead of $_SERVER.

Comment: _“on localhost my site has this address - `localhost/example.com`”_ - then _that_ is what I would fix here, if I were you. Create a proper virtual host for each of your sites.